# How to make 2nd element get rest of the horizontal space

Tags: html, css, layout, width

I want to make first input have the width 100% and second + image = 100% so that second input get the rest of the space (100%-img size) on the same line. Is it possible to do using CSS?

`<html><head><title>width test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.t {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;

}
.caption {
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
}
.data {
    text-align: left;
    width: 65%;
}
.edt {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="t">
    <tr>
        <td class="caption">Caption:</td>
        <td class="data"><input type="text" class="edt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="caption">Caption:</td>
        <td class="data">
            <input type="text" class="edt" /><a href="#"><img width="22px" src="cal.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I can do it with tables. The question still remain, is it possible to do with div/css?

`<html><head><title>width test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.t {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;

}
.caption {
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
}
.data {
    text-align: left;
    width: 65%;
}
.edt {
    width: 100%;
}
.joiningtable
{
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.joiningrest
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.joiningfixed
{
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="t">
    <tr>
        <td class="caption">Caption:</td>
        <td class="data"><input type="text" class="edt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="caption">Caption:</td>
        <td class="data">
            <table class="joiningtable">
                <tr><td class="joiningrest"><input type="text" class="edt" /></td><td class="joiningfixed"><a href="#"><img src="cal.png" /></a></td><tr>
            <table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with CSS. The trick is to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, where where `width: 100%` means "the rest of the available space".

Here is an example (with wrapper divs around `.edt` and the image link for better result): http://jsfiddle.net/zgw8q7vj/

The important CSS parts are these:

```
/*Use "table" layout in the 'data' cells, 
  and give them all the available width (after the captions)*/
.data {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
/*Then give the textbox all the available remaining width...*/
.edt-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
/*...after the image has claimed the space it needs*/
.img-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

If you don't want the caption column to take more space than it needs, you can even remove `table-layout:fixed;` and `width: 35%;` from `.t` and `.caption`

Comment: Thank you @Sphinxxx Which browsers it will work on? Would it work in IE6?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but after testing it from IE11's "emulation mode", it only works on IE8 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

untested.
you didn't mention colspans can't be used, so this solution uses it.

```
<table class="t">
    <tr>
        <td class="caption">Caption:</td>
        <td class="data"><input type="text" class="edt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="caption">Caption:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="edt" /></td>
        <td class="data"><a href="#"><img width="22px" src="cal.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case this outer table structure is fixed, so I can't do it your way (

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested, it is possible but you need to use a little magic..

With absolute positioning, you can stretch those entry fields as wide as you like, or rather, you make them stretch to 100% and put them inside spans that stretch as wide as you like because input fields are stubborn things and won't behave otherwise.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color:#DDDDFF; position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px; right:10px; height:80px;">
<span style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px;">Caption</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:40px;">Caption</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:70px; top:10px; right:10px;">
<input type="text" style="width:100%" />
</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:70px; top:40px; right:40px;">
<input type="text" style="width:100%" />
</span>
<img style="width:22px; position:absolute; top:40px; right:10px;" src="cal.png" />
</div>
<div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I've left the style definitions on the entities for simplicity. In a real-world case, I'd move them to a .css file of course.